# Changing Emacs bindings in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, emacs

I'm trying to reset the binding for "C-x C-c".  Specifically, I want to rebind it to a function that asks me if I really want to quit (I just fat finger it way too much).  I've done this before under Linux with no issues.  Under Mac OS X, when I evaluate the expression

```
(global-unset-key “\C-x\C-c”)
```

I get:

> eval-buffer: Symbol's value as variable is void: “C-xC-c”

So, why is it void?  The command does exit Emacs, so it can't be `void`.  I must not be referring to "C-x C-c" correctly.  But what is the correct way?

I get the same problem when using `global-set-key` to bind the command sequence to a new function.

I'm using GNU Emacs 23.0.0 from MacPorts and Mac OS X 10.5 (Leopard).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somehow, you are using smartquotes.

Use

```
(global-unset-key "\C-x\C-c")  ;; use this
```

instead of

```
(global-unset-key “\C-x\C-c”)  ;; Not this one!
```

Comment: This was the problem.  I copied the code from a website.  Somehow, all the quotes (single and double) became smartquotes.

Comment: A fair number of websites (say, all the WordPress blogs in the world that haven't been tweaked) will force change *all* quotes to smart-quotes. It's a plague for code copying.

Answer (score 5):

Emacs has a configuration for what you asked that does not require to touch the C-x C-c binding.

Just add to your config one of the following:

```
(setq confirm-kill-emacs 'y-or-n-p)

(setq confirm-kill-emacs 'yes-or-no-p)
```

The first one will you ask you to type a single character y/n for confirmation, while the second one will ask you the full answer yes/no.

Answer (score -2):

This is a start, here is a somewhat relevant page http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/emacs/emacs_496.html , but it seems what you want is to redefine the binding, not to remove it.  Or just always have a modified file around, that way it will ask before quitting (and you could automate that in  your .emacs or ~/.emacs.d/init.el )

http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/emacs/emacs_502.html

Comment: Those don't help much.  I know what I want to do, and I'm fairly confident I'm going about it in the right manner.  I don't understand how to represent C-x C-c.  What I think I've used in the past is not working here.

Comment: That is a really old manual.  The OP is on Emacs 23.  C-h i, or if you really want to read it on the web, http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/emacs.html